# S/MIME certificate not trusted

Tags: ios, icloud, mail.app, certificate

I actually own a S/MIME certificate for my e-mail address. I got no problem installing it on my Mac, and it perfectly works with Apple Mail (except the encryption icon that is greyed out, but I don't use it anyway), I can sign my emails without any issue.
Here is the catch: when I try to use my certificate on Apple Mail for iPhone, I can install the certificate profile but it appears as 'Not signed', then 'Not Trusted'. I can toggle on that certificate in the iCloud Mail settings, but it won't show any option to sign digitally my emails in the Mail app.
Please note that my certificate is provided by a trusted issuer.

Any idea why and how to solve this issue?